# ng-include causes the controller block to re render

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use ng-switch with ng-include below. The problem is with ng-init and the whole controller block getting re-rendered on any ng-includes change.

In the login_form.html, when a user logins, I set the isLoggedIn = true, in the LoginCtrl. However this causes the re-rendering of the full html below, which causes the ng-init again.

How do I avoid this cycle?

```
      <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-init="isLoggedIn = false" class="span4 pull-right">
        <div ng-switch on="isLoggedIn"> 
          <div ng-switch-when="false" ng-include src="'login_form.html'"></div>
          <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-include src="'profile_links.html'"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Below is the HTML for the login form -

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="userEmail" class="input-small"/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="userPassword" class="input-small"/>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="login(userEmail, userPassword)" class="btn">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Below is the controller -

```
angularApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, currentUser){

  $scope.loginStatus = function(){
    return currentUser.isLoggedIn();
  };

/*  $scope.$on('login', function(event, args) {
    $scope.userName = args.name;
  }); 

  $scope.$on('logout', function(event, args) {
    $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
  });*/

  $scope.login = function(email, password){
    currentUser.login(email, password);
  };

  $scope.logout = function(){
    currentUser.logout();
  };

});
```

Blow is the service -

```
angularApp.factory('currentUser', function($rootScope) {
  // Service logic
  // ...
  // 
    var allUsers = {"rob@gmail.com": {name: "Robert Patterson", role: "Admin", email: "rob@gmail.com", password: "rob"},
            "steve@gmail.com":{name: "Steve Sheldon", role: "User", email: "steve@gmail.com", password: "steve"}}

  var isUserLoggedIn = false;

  // Public API here
  return {
    login: function(email, password){
      var user = allUsers[email];
      var storedPass = user.password;

      if(storedPass === password){
        isUserLoggedIn = true;
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    },
    logout: function(){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('logout');
      isUserLoggedIn = false;
    },

    isLoggedIn: function(){
      return isUserLoggedIn;
    }
 };
});
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe your problem is a result of the way prototypal inheritance works.  ng-include creates its own child scope.  Assigning a primitive value in a child scope creates a new property on that scope that shadows/hides the parent property.

I'm guessing that in login_form.html you do something like the following when a user logs in:

```
<a ng-click="isLoggedIn=true">login</a>
```

Before isLoggedIn is set to true, this is what your scopes look like:

[image: before assignment]

After isLoggedIn is set to true, this is what your scopes look like:

[image: after assignment]

Hopefully the pictures make it clear why this is causing you problems.

For more information about why prototypal inheritance works this way with primitives, please see [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

As the above link explains, you have three solutions:

1. define an object in the parent for your model, then reference a property of that object in the child: parentObj.isLoggedIn
2. use $parent.isLoggedIn in login_form.html -- this will then reference the primitive in the $parent scope, rather than create a new one.  E.g.,
   `<a ng-click="$parent.isLoggedIn=true">login</a>`
3. define a function on the parent scope, and call it from the child -- e.g., setIsLoggedIn().  This will ensure the parent scope property is being set, not a child scope property.

**Update**: in reviewing your HTML, you may actually have two levels of child scopes, since ng-switch and ng-include each create their own scopes.  So, the pictures would need a grandchild scope, but the three solutions are the same... except for #2, where you would need to use $parent.$parent.isLoggedIn -- ugly.  So I suggest option 1 or 3.

**Update2**: @murtaza52 added some code to the question...  Remove `ng-init="isLoggedIn = false"` from your controller (your service is managing the login state via its `isUserLoggedIn` variable) and switch on loginStatus() in your controller: `<div ng-switch on="loginStatus()">`.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/PCNaQ/).

Comment: I suppose my answer is solution 1?

Comment: @asgoth, well, your fiddle uses essentially solution 1, although there is yet another child scope due to the additional controllers.  Your "one controller" answer uses essentially solution 3 -- you are calling a function in the parent scope (which is available to child scopes due to prototypal inheritance) to change a parent scope property.  But then there is a bit of solution 1 in there too, due to the parent object property -- you can use a primitive with solution 3.  Here's a [fiddle for solution 3](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/jNxyE/) that uses a primitive in the parent scope.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer Mark. Let me implement your solution and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Mark I have added the code for the service and controller I have and also the login_form.html. Even after I sign in the loginStatus() still returns false. My hunch is this due to the var isUserLoggedIn being reset to false, in the service 'currentUser'

Comment: @murtaza52, see Update2 in my answer.

Comment: What happens when you have a directive with an isolated scope and the directive expects a primitive? Would `<some-directive prim-val="$parent.myPrimitive" />` also work?

Answer (score 3):

I've have a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/WjBNq/). The trick is that the scope variable to be evaluated  has to be an object, not a primitive type. It looks like `$scope.$watch()` is not watching primitive types properly (which is a bug). The jsFiddle has a parent controller with two child controllers, but it would also work with only one (parent) controller.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="LoginCheckCtrl">
        <div ng-switch on="user.login"> 
          <div ng-switch-when="false" ng-include="'login'"></div>
          <div ng-switch-when="true" ng-include="'logout'"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function LoginCheckCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        login: false
    };
}
```

**Note:** this will also work with only one controller:

```
function LoginCheckCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        login: false
    };
    $scope.login = function() {
        console.log($scope.user.login ? 'logged in' : 'not logged in');
        $scope.user.login = true;
    };
    $scope.logout = function() {
        console.log($scope.user.login ? 'logged in' : 'not logged in');
        $scope.user.login = false;
    };
}
```

Comment: This also results in the same behavior. The re-rendering still resets the variable. Any ideas on how to prevent rerendering or reset ?

Comment: Just saw, my jsfiddle went into an endless loop :)

Comment: Edited my answer. Check the example in the link.

Comment: +1 for your comment and +1 for answer. The solution you have suggested depends upon creating separate controllers for each control. I think that is the better approach, and I will use it. However any idea on  why any variables in the controller are reset ?

Comment: Each include has its own controller, but they inherit the parent. So, $scope.user is only defined on the parent. The variables are reset because they are primitive types, not because they are in the same controller. I just tested it, by removing the child controllers (and defining the function on the parent).

Comment: "any idea on why any variables in the controller are reset ?" -- most likely they are not getting reset.  I believe a new isLoggedIn property is being created on a child scope that is hiding/shadowing the parent property of the same name.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: I have updated my post with the complete code. Also please check the comment I left for Mark under his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the state that needs to survive the reinitialization of the controller in a parent scope. I don't think it's strange to put isLoggedIn on the $rootScope even.

Also, you could initialize inside the controller, that would be cleaner in this case (but it doesn't solve your problem).