# ng-if wrapping a select ng-options breaks ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This plunker is from Angular `ngOptions` sample:

[ngOption/Select Angular Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/hq8Fzod28hFbjoVUdInC?p=preview)

However, I added an `ngIf` to the first `select` resulting in:

```
<div ng-if="1<2">
    Color (null not allowed):
    <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select><br>
</div>
```

Something interesting that you may notice is that the `ngIf` breaks the `ngModel` binding and nothing happens when you change your selection.

Because the same code without the `ngIf` produces the expected results.

Can you please confirm if this is a bug in angular, my code and/or if there is a work around it?

Comment: ng-if creates a child scope. I cannot see the plunker.. so exactly not sure if that is what the issue is. So you may be setting `myColor` in the child scope and trying to access it in the parent scope? Check this http://jsbin.com/namimimaqe/1/edit

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong

Comment: This is an awesome explanation.. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101099/ng-include-causes-the-controller-block-to-re-render/14104318#14104318

Answer (score 2):

Using the ng-if directive creates a new scope for the DOM inside it. To reference the myColor variable on the parent scope, write ng-model="$parent.myColor"

```
<div ng-if="1<2">
    Color (null not allowed):
    <select ng-model="$parent.myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in colors"></select><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  add $parent to your ng-options as ng-if creating child scope

please see below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [{
    name: "red"
  }, {
    name: "black"
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <div ng-if="1<2">
      Color (null not allowed):
      <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in $parent.colors"></select>
      <br>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

or use controller as syntax ie:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl as vm ">

    <div ng-if="1<2">
      Color (null not allowed):
      <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="color.name for color in vm.colors"></select>
      <br>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**JS**
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function() {

  var vm = this;
  vm.colors = [{
    name: "red"
  }, {
    name: "black"
  }]


});
```

Comment: No no no `$parent`, it is bad... There are many other better ways to handle this.