# Angular scoping issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem where by a form within my `ng-controller` doesnt seem to change the properties in the controller that I thought it would.  After some reading around it seems I wasn't fully aware of prototypal inheritance, but thanks to the [internet](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101099/ng-include-causes-the-controller-block-to-re-render/14104318#14104318) I updated my code as such. But unfortunately its still not working and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my HTML

```
<div ng-app="licenceApp" ng-controller="licenceController">    
    <div class="hover panel" ng-class="{switch : licenceFormVisible}">
        <div class="highlightedSection nosidepad clearfix back">  
            <div class="highlightedSubSection" ng-class="{fullsize : uploadModel.active}" ng-show="!Applying && !FinishedWithErrors && !offlineActivationScreenVisible">
                <h2>Licence File</h2>
                Upload and apply a valid licence file{{uploadModel.active}}<br /><br />
                ...
                <form id="hiddenUploadForm" name="hiddenUploadForm" target="hiddenUploadFormFileTarget" action="/settings/uploadILP" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: none;">
                    <input id="hiddenUploadFormFile" name="file" type="file" ng-model="uploadModel.uploadFileName" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFileChanged()" />
                    <iframe id="hiddenUploadFormFileTarget" name="hiddenUploadFormFileTarget" iframe-onload="uploadFileFinished()"></iframe>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ViewModel

```
angular.module('licenceApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('licenceController', ['$scope', 'licenceAPIservice', '$filter', '$timeout', function ($scope, licenceAPIservice, $filter, $timeout) {
        $scope.uploadModel = {
            active: false,
            uploadFileName: "",
            uploading: false
        };

        $scope.uploadFileChanged = function () {
            $scope.uploadModel.active = true;
            $scope.uploadModel.uploading = true;

            $('#hiddenUploadForm').submit();
        }
        ...
```

So when I change `uploadModel.active` in a function it shows the correct value through a `console.log` but the display doesnt mimic the new value! Am I still subject to prototypal inheritance here? Note that `uploadFileChanged` is hit when the input file control is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onchange is a javascript event outside angular so you would need to call `$apply` to notify angular of the  changes in the scope. Fortunately there is a angular directive that does that for you ([ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)).

```
<input id="hiddenUploadFormFile" 
       name="file" type="file" 
       ng-model="uploadModel.uploadFileName"
       ng-change="uploadFileChanged()" />
```

EDIT:

ngModel doesn't work with input type=file ([issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375)), hence ngChange won't work as it required ngModel to work.

The right way to approach it then would be to call $apply inside you uploadFileChanged function.

HTML:

```
<input id="hiddenUploadFormFile" 
       name="file" type="file" 
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFileChanged()"/>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.uploadFileChanged = function () {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.uploadModel.active = true;
          $scope.uploadModel.uploading = true;
          $('#hiddenUploadForm').submit();
        });
    }
```

If you plan to use input type file, it might be work to create a simple directive that handles the change event without the need to access the element scope that way.

Comment: Yes I just double checked and it doesnt work with inputs.. In this case do I just need to use $apply within my function?

Comment: ngChange only requires ngModel to work, so if the input field has ngModel it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. If I add that code I get an error on the apply line which is: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: It was `$apply` :D - ok so thats great and it works, thankyou.  But can I ask why? Why do I need to apply when in other functions I dont? It must have found the scope as the function was executed?

Comment: Because of the way two-way data binding works, when you change a property in $scope that a it's being used in your template angular needs to be informed when that property change in some way and the way that it uses is called $digest which is a recursive function that travels accross all scopes  checking for equality checks in the fields that it's supposed to keep in sync with the template.

Comment: Why do I not need to do this under normal execution?

Comment: Because you are inside angular context, meaning an angular directive/controller/service all does methods are called within $digest or they trigger a $digest.